# How to select one shape from many shapes in canvas and move that particular shape in android canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, touch-event, ondraw

In the android canvas, I have 5 shapes. In my case, I need to select one of them and move to new position. The same time need to find which one select by touch.

Answer (score 0):

If You have drawn shapes by x, y coordinate and by width height then implement OnTouchListener interface and take touch of whole screen. Take touch coordinate x and y and match on onTouch implement method in which shape coordinate are touched.